# Eddy Installation Error: Child Process Exited with Code 100

Tags: linux, deb

During the installation of any .deb package using Eddy on Pop.OS, I encounter the following error message, leading to a premature termination of the installation process:

`com.github.dinadigo.eddy Child process failed, exited with error number 100`

How can I solve this issue?

I've tried installing other .deb packages to determine whether the problem was specific to the initially installed .deb package. However, the issue persisted across all installations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue while updating Visual Studio Code and managed to solve it by running:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

As seen in this tutorial: https://support.system76.com/articles/package-manager-pop/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing R-Studio. I followed the instructions here in Maximo's answer but got the same error. when I tried installing R-studio through the terminal I was met with a dependency error with libssl, see: https://community.rstudio.com/t/dependency-error-when-installing-rstudio-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-libssl/135397. I resolved the error using the following code:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I then added the following lines to the file:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main
```

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main

Ctrl + o to save and then Enter.

I then installed the following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.2`/openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz`
```

Extracted the source code:

```
tar -xvf openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz
```

And finally ran the installation:

```
 cd openssl-1.0.2u
./config
make
sudo make install
```

And it worked.